# Prove ratio of sines inequality

Tags: trigonometry

Prove that $$\frac{\alpha_1}{\alpha_2}<\frac{\sin \alpha_1}{\sin \alpha_2} $$ for all $0<\alpha_1,\alpha_2<\pi/2$ and $\alpha_1<\alpha_2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Show $f(t) = \frac{\sin t}t$ is a decreasing function on $(0, \pi/2]$.

Comment: I can see how that directly applies to prove the original statement: sinc(alpha1)>sinc(alpha2). I show the decreasing behavior of sinc via derivative<0 leading to \alpha<\tan\alpha which then is easy to settle using another derivative. Thank you!